# update item of array of array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I want to push an item to the array of items (root document > categories > subcategories > items)

I am using NodeJS with MongoDB npm package

My document structure should be like the following

```
{
    "_id": "572a77641b24ed3404f43690"
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "572bbac072d7ee3026a69467"
            "Name": "Foods",
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "id": "572a777c1b24ed3404f43691",
                    "Name": "Pizza"
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "id": "572ba1666ca263303121acd4"
                            "Name": "4 Seasons",
                            "Price": "6.0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My current code is

```
app.post("/item/:subcatid", function(req, res) {
    var subId = req.params.subcatid;
    var item = req.body;

    item.id = new ObjectId();

    items.update({ "categories.subcategories.id": ObjectId(subId) }, { $push: { "categories.0.subcategories.$.items": item } }, function(err, result) {
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

What can I do ?

Comment: actually this is working but it will update the first category, it wont be helpful if I want to update a specific category, it always goes to the very first one !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution, not clean one though but works properly !

```
app.post("/item/:subcatid", function(req, res) {
    var subId = req.params.subcatid;
    var item = req.body;

    item.id = new ObjectId();

    items.findOne({ "categories.subcategories.id": ObjectId(subId) }, { "categories.subcategories.$": 1 }, function(err, doc) {
        for (var i = 0; i < doc.categories[0].subcategories.length; i++) {
            var elem = doc.categories[0].subcategories[i];
            if (elem.id == subId) {
                items.update({ "categories.subcategories.id": ObjectId(subId) }, { $push: { ["categories." + i + ".subcategories.$.items"]: item } }, function(err, result) {
                    res.send(result);
                });

                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```